# I cannot set Repeat Header Rows of table in report rtf

Tags: oracle, ms-word, rtf

I create report rtf by MS word2013 and use source code from oracle xml report.

ex xml code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <!--  Generated by Oracle Reports version 6.0.8.28.0 -->
```

Problem : I cannot set Repeat Header Rows of a table.
I setup table 
1. Properties
2. At tab row check "Repeat as header row at the top of each page"

Result : table is not Repeat header

[image]

How should I do? Please suggest me.